# Receiving syntax error while using ADOQuery to insert into database

Tags: ado, delphi-2010

All names and data types were checked to ensure no incorrect info/fields were used.

A `with Datamodule` was stated at the top of the code, but there is too much to post from the rest, this is the only part which doesn't work:

```
sEncPass :=  objAlgorithms.CipherEn(sPass,13);
//start insert code
qryUserInfo.SQL.Clear;
qryUserInfo.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO LoginInfo(ID,Login,Password)');
qryUserInfo.SQL.Add('VALUES(:ID,:Login,:Password)');
with qryUserInfo.Parameters do
begin
  ParamByName('ID').Value := sID;
  ParamByName('Login').Value := sUsername;
  ParamByName('Password').Value := sEncPass;
end;
qryUserInfo.ExecSQL;
qryUserInfo.SQL.Clear;
qryUserInfo.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO CustomerInfo(ID,Name,Surname,TelNo,Email)');
qryUserInfo.SQL.Add('VALUES (:ID,:Name,:Surname,:TelNo,:Email)');
with qryUserInfo.Parameters do
begin
  ParamByName('ID').Value := sID;
  ParamByName('Name').Value:= sName;
  ParamByName('Surname').Value:= sSurname;
  ParamByName('TelNo').Value:= sCell;
  ParamByName('Email').Value:= sRAddres;
end;
qryUserInfo.ExecSQL;
```

The fields I am using in the DB (all are strings):

[image]

Comment: Please consider posting the actual error message that you received as well to help others out when trying to answer your question.

Comment: Is `qryUserInfo.ParamCheck` set to True?

Comment: @Remy yeah the ParamCheck was and still is on true

Comment: @BrandonHaugen the error is "Project Project1.exe raised exception class EOleException with message 'Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement'." i made sure all the names are without spaces and copy-pasted all the field names and table names into that statement so it can't be an error with the name of fields.

Comment: You have two separate INSERT statements (one into LoginInfo, one into CustomerInfo). Which one is raising the exception? What are the actual values of the variables that you're passing to the parameters of that query?

Comment: @KenWhite from what i tried and gathered at this point its the first statement as the second one has a relationship and needs the primary key to be entered in LoginInfo first.

Comment: Why are you guessing? Use the debugger, step through the code, and see which one specifically is raising the exception. Which one is it, and what are the actual values you're putting into the parameters to it?

Comment: @KenWhite i am not guessing i can tell you it is the first one 100% it does give me the error at first one and the values i am putting in go like this: sID = 'C002',sUsername = 'PurryFury' , sPassword = '123456789'

Comment: So `sEncPass :=  objAlgorithms.CipherEn(sPass,13);` returns `123456789`? Not much of a cypher. :-) I'd suggest looking at the content of `sEncPass` to see what *specifically* it contains just before the exception is raised. My suspicion is that it's generating an invalid character (like a misplaced quote character, for instance), but we can't debug that from here for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone who helped, found a fix by adding `` ` `` to the field names:

```
qryUserInfo.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO CustomerInfo(`ID`,`Name`,`Surname`,`TelNo`,`Email`)');
```